# How to specify ErrorDocument for a VirtualHost in Apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, errordocument

I have an Apache 2 server and it have several vhosts with similar definition:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/host1/
    ServerName host1.loc
    <Directory /var/www/html/host1>
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options AuthConfig
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/host2/
    ServerName host2.loc
    <Directory /var/www/html/host2>
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options AuthConfig
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
</VirtualHost>
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/hostN/
    ServerName hostN.loc
    <Directory /var/www/html/hostN>
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options AuthConfig
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to customize page 404.

The problem is that when I try to test 404 page in any of the hosts, I can see the page from the very last vhost. What could be wrong with my config?

Comment: What happens when you change it into a static message like `ErrorDocument 404 "File not found on vhost hostN"`? Do you get the right messages? Try placing the `ErrorDocument` directive inside of the `Directory` directive.

Comment: Could you update your post with at least two <virtualHost>...</virtualHost> directive you have ?

Comment: @dtech, it looks like there is no effect. It looks like this directive is completely ignored in every vhost except the very last one.

Comment: @user2196728, I added several more of them

Comment: ok thanks ! can you try with full fqdn and path to index.php for each vhost ErrorDocument, instead of just "/index.php?error=404" ?

Comment: yes, the direct link works

Comment: I have just found the reason: there was .htaccess file with incorrect rewrite rules :(

Comment: "what about .htaccess ?" was planed to be my next question :) glad it works

Answer (score 2):

Put ErrorDocument directives inside Directory tag.

Trunk: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/custom-error.html

2.2: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument

> Custom error documents are configured using the ErrorDocument
>   directive, which may be used in global, virtualhost, or directory
>   context. It may be used in .htaccess files if AllowOverride is set to
>   FileInfo.

Comment: When triggering 404 via code, also make sure to manually include the 404 page, as the apache server does not do that on its own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1381220/2126442

Answer (score -4):

Use an html file instead of php one.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /custom_error_404.html
```

Comment: I am quite sure a php file can be used for custom 404...or other